# Refresh(recreate) the activities in back stack when change locale at run time

Tags: android, onresume, recreate

I have an Activity say `ActivityMain` from this activity I moved to another activity called `ActivitySettings` and in settings activity I'm changing the App locale by clicking on a button, and using recreate I achieved the change I need in current activity but when I press back my `ActivityMain' will resume but locale is not updated.

Can some one tell me how to 'Recreate' backstack activities? what will be the correct approach.

I can't call recreate on refresh as it will be infinite loop

Comment: Look at here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In each Activity's `onCreate()` you can maintain the `currentLangCode`. Check this value in `onResume()`, if it differs, you can conclude the locale was change and `recreate()`

You can do it as follows:

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity{
    private String currentLangCode;
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        currentLangCode = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();
        ...
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        ...
        if(!currentLangCode.equals(getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage())){
            currentLangCode = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();
            recreate();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

### **My Recommendation**

If you want to apply it for all the Activities, then simply create BaseActivity as follows:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private String currentLangCode;
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        currentLangCode = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();
        ...
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        ...
        if(!currentLangCode.equals(getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();)){
            currentLangCode = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();
            recreate();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Extend all Activities from `BaseActivity`

```
public class ActivityA extends BaseActivity{

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
      super.onResume();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sure. Let me know.

Comment: getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage() this this is not giving changed language it is still giving me old lang and the condition is always flase I made a work around by checking with shareprefs where i'm saving the changed language

Comment: @Praneeth, just tested the value, its returning correct value for me.

Comment: @Praneeth, same to me