# Android locale file not loaded

Tags: android, kotlin, localization, locale

The app supports os 8.0+

I have added the `values-ar` folder with support for `strings.xml` . If I change the language from phone settings to arabic, the app loads the correct resources.
If I set the default locale at runtime in `Application` class, it fails to load the specific **("ar")** resources.

[image: d]

This is how I change conf (on `Application` class):

```
fun changeDefaultLocale() {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale("ar")
        val configuration = resources.configuration
        configuration.setLocale(locale)
        this.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
    }
```

What I have tried:

- rename `values-ar` to `values-ar-rEG`
- add `resConfigs "en", "ar"` on `app/build.gradle`
- add `android:configChanges="locale"` to `Manifest/<application`
- use `Locale("ar","AE")` or `Locale("ar","EG")`

I had put a break point on the row after I called the above `changeDefaultLocale()` fun:

[image]

Why it doesn't load the correct resource file? I repeat, if I change it from the phone settings it works correctly.

**UPDATE**

Using @Nurbol response I have updated the `BaseActivity` as below, and it's working fine. My problem now is:

`Activity A` -> `Activity B (here I switch the locale)`, then if I press back and the sistem restores `Activity A`, **it has the old configuration, and the old locale. How to overcome that?**

```
override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(updateBaseContextLocale(base))
}

private fun updateBaseContextLocale(context: Context): Context {
    val locale = Locale("ar")
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    return updateResourcesLocale(context, locale)
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private fun updateResourcesLocale(context: Context, locale: Locale): Context {
    val configuration = context.resources.configuration
    configuration.setLocale(locale)
    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097334/refreshrecreate-the-activities-in-back-stack-when-change-locale-at-run-time

found here the answer to the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Changing *locale*s programmaticaly is not suggested. Cause it is buggy. If you really want to change it. You should call `changeDefaultLocale()` method within every activity's `onCreate()` befor `setContentView()`. You can simply create *BaseActivity* class that does that and use it as parent class of every activity.

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Change locale settings in the app.
        val dm = resources.displayMetrics
        val conf = resources.configuration
        val lang = "ar"

        conf.setLocale(Locale(lang.toLowerCase())) // API 17+ only.

        resources.updateConfiguration(conf, dm)
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Try it out @ghita

Comment: it does change the rtl configuration (so the layout switched from right to left) but it still doesn't read the proper `strings.xml` file. I'ved also added  `Locale.setDefault(Locale("ar")` to your method, no effect;

Comment: Use updated above code. Deprecated but works @ghita

Comment: thank you for your answer Nurbol, I have found a solution based on your answer, I'ved updated the question.